# Integration in order to derive formulas for self-inductance

Tags: coordinate-systems, conventions, integration, inductance

When deriving formulas for Self Inductance, I stumbled upon the following integration:

$$\frac{V_o}{L}\int_0^tsinωtdt=\int_0^t\frac{dI}{dt}$$

The result logically is:
$$-\frac{V_o}{ωL}cosωt +constant = I(t)$$

The book then says that we can get rid of the constant by using t = 0.

Can somebody explain the logic of using t = 0 in order to get rid of the constant here?

Comment: The idea is that you can determine the constant if you know the actual value of I(t) for some value of t. Is it true that the value of I(t) at t=0 is known? If so, then it should be a simple matter to determine the constant by evaluating your equation at t=0.

Comment: at t=0, I(t) comes out -(Vo/ωL), but I do not have a numerical value for it...

Comment: You mean that you have independent information given in the problem that I(t) is equal to $-(V_o/\omega L)$ at t=0? If so, then just evaluate your 2nd equation at t=0 and the constant is determined. No need to know the numerical value of $-(V_o/\omega L)$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake here:
I reasoned that it should be 0 based on the formula, but that is by ignoring the constant… My mistake!
There is no independent information anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Using $t=0$ as a base is arbitrary mathematically but sensible intuitively as for many problems we know an initial state and it makes sense to assign that time to zero.

But mathematically :

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{dI}{dt}dt = I(t_2)-I(t_2)$$

No matter what values you use for $t_1$ and $t_2$ the constant of integration cancels out.

There are circumstances (different physical systems) where you might know the value of a function at e.g. $t\to \infty$ and you need to determine the constant of integration from that.  What value of $t$ you use to determine the constant of integration depends on what you know about the system.